# Android cache Web response

Tags: java, android, caching, squid, jcs

I'm developing an application where I need to cache the response from urls the user visits. So is there a good caching system like [jcs](http://commons.apache.org/jcs/) available already? Or a port of `squid` for java(android java) would do. Do I need to write my own caching system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JCS and Squid are probably too heavyweight for what you need.  If you are just caching some text, I would think a simple map based approach would work for you.  If you need to persist this data, a database or file would probably work better.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4 the `HttpUrlConnection` is able to cache responses. See http://practicaldroid.blogspot.de/2013/01/utilizing-http-response-cache.html.